# Simple Java Game

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a java game.

There is a Slider(S) piece that can move one square in a north-west-south-east direction. There is a Diag(D) piece that can move one square in any diagonal direction. And there is a Jumper(J) piece that teleports randomly to any square on the board. 
Slider moves first, then Diag, and then Jumper in that order. If one piece lands on another, then the latter is eliminated from the game. For instance, if Jumper lands on Diagonal, then Diagonal is removed for the rest of the game.

```
. . . . .    
. . . . .     
. . s . d    
. . . . .    
. . . . j
```

It should look something like that in the command prompt. 
I only have the basic outline of the program and I don't know how to start it. ._. The teacher said we could try using arrays although we didn't learn it yet. Just a general direction on where to go would be very helpful. The code I have now is:

```
public class Collide {
    Piece s1, d1, j1;       
    int count;  


public Collide(){
    //initialize pieces
    s1 = new Slider();
    d1 = new Diag();
    j1 = new Jumper();
}

public void play(){

}

public static void main(String [] args){
    Collide collide = new Collide();
    collide.play();
}
}

class Piece {
int x, y;       
boolean alive;
public void movePiece(){}    
}

class Slider extends Piece {
    int g;
    public void movePiece(){ 
    g = (int)(Math.random()*4)+1;
}}

 class Diag extends Piece {
    public void movePiece(){ 

}    }

class Jumper extends Piece{
    int w = (int)(Math.random()*25)+1;
    public void movePiece(){
}}
```

Comment: Since you have not included an actual question, I presume it is either "Can you do my homework for me?" or "Can you magically turn me into a programmer?" Is that correct?

Comment: Im just wondering is it possible to do it with arrays

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You should use a two-dimensional array (probably `Object[][] field`).

Answer (score 0):

i would give you a little example for the slider.

```
 char[][] arrayLengthD = new char[5][5];  //declaration of the array
```

fill it with two for loops

```
            for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j<5; j++) {
                    arrayLengthD[i][j] = '.';
                }
            }
```

now you only have to put a if condition in the  inner for loop which checks if the i and j is == the x and y coordinates of your slider, when it is true: arrayLengthD[i][j] = 's';
And while reading the x and y coordinates for the slider from user input, you can check it like this:

```
 if((y==i&&x!=j)||(x==j&&y!=i))
```

so if this condition is true, the moving is only in one direction and not diagonally.
And dont forget to put the whole game logic in a while loop!